# Is there any column equivalent as num_distinct all_tab_columns(Oracle) in MSSQL for Metadata?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a table which is same as all_tab_columns which has num_distinct column which is in oracle. And I need the same in MSSQL

Could anybody help me find Num_distinct in MSSQL Metadata tables?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For columns that are part of an index, SQL Server's [DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql) returns a `density` which is the inverse of Oracle's `NUM_DISTINCT`

Note the following caveat from the documentation:

```
If target is the name of an existing column, and an automatically created statistics on this column exists, information about that auto-created statistic is returned. If an automatically created statistic does not exist for a column target, error message 2767 is returned.
```

Statistics can not be gathered on non-indexed columns.  So I think that there is no equivalent.